# onchange="this.form.submit()" versus two submit buttons

Tags: javascript, forms

With a pulldown triggering an onchange event to submit, it fails to work when two input submit buttons are present. It makes sense, so how do you specify exclusively which submit button to process?

```
<form>
<select onchange="this.form.submit()"></select>
<input type="submit" name="submit1" id="submit1" value="Submit 1" />
<input type="submit" name="submit2" id="submit2" value="Submit 2" />
</form>
```

**Solution**
Using the suggestion from below, this code will work so that the second submit button will execute if the onchange is trigged from the pulldown:

```
<form>
<select onchange="var e=document.getElementById('killbox'); var s=document.getElementById('submit1'); e.removeChild(s); this.form.submit();"></select>
<div id="killbox"><input type="submit" name="submit1" id="submit1" value="Submit 1" /></div>
<input type="submit" name="submit2" id="submit2" value="Submit 2" />
</form>
```

This is in a basic form, certainly doesn't hurt to throw the Javascript in to a function instead of using inline Javascript for the onchange.

Comment: My english ir very poor and I understand that you some of your `submit` doesn't works? Is that right ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can simply call `.submit()` on the button itself: `document.getElementById('submit1').submit()`

-edit-

Solution two: just remove one of the buttons (use `removeChild()`, which is a common DOM method).

Comment: I already tried that and it didn't work. It seems that only forms can be submitted, not input buttons.

Answer (score 6):

this is another form that can be used

```html
<select class="form-control" id="search" name="search" value="search" onchange="this.form.submit()">
  <option>1</option>  
    <option>2</option>  
    <option>3</option>  
     
  </select>
```

Comment: I like this kind of approach for its simplicity. It's not pretty but its light, simple and functional.

Answer (score 2):

You could fire a click event on the button you want to use to submit. It feels weird, but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

as Mathletics suggested, fire the submit via onclick

```
<form name="oh" action="/">
<select onchange="oWhichSubmit(this)" onkeypress="oWhichSubmit(this)">
<option value=""></option><option value="submit1">Submit1</option><option value="submit2">Submit2</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit1" id="submit1" value="Submit 1" />
<input type="submit" name="submit2" id="submit2" value="Submit 2" />
</form>
```

gets the selected option's value used to referencing the submit element

```
 <script>
function oWhichSubmit(thisSubmit){
  var oWhich = thisSubmit.value;   
     if(document.getElementById(oWhich)){
      document.getElementById(oWhich).click();
    }
}
</script>
```